# Prove that it's a Linear Functional (Kronecker delta)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Suppose that $dim(V) = n$ and that $B = \{e_1,...,e_n \}$ is a basis for $V$. Then we define $B^{*} = \{e^1,...,e^n \}$ such that:
>
> \begin{equation}
> e^{i}(e_{j}) = \delta_{j}^{i} = \begin{cases}1, \quad \text{if} \; i = j \\ 0, \quad \text{if} i \neq j \end{cases}
> \end{equation}
>
> Show that each $e^{i}$ is a linear functional of $V$.

I guess that I have to show that it obeys these two conditions:

\begin{equation}
f(u + v) = f(u) + f(v) \qquad \alpha f(u) = f(\alpha u)
\end{equation}

But I'm really stuck in how to do this. The second part, show that $\alpha f(u) = f(\alpha u)$, looks kinda obvious, something like just substituing $f$ for $e^{i}$ and $u$ for $e_j$ from the statement above:

\begin{equation}
\alpha e^{i}(e_{j}) = e^{i}(\alpha e_{j})
\end{equation}

But I'm convinced that this is totally wrong, because is too simple and I don't use the conditions ($i=j$ or $i \neq j$). And for the first part I'm really confused in how to do this. All help is appreciated!

Comment: The functions $e^i$ are only given on the *basis elements*, and so there is exactly one way to *extend* it to a linear functional.